# binary search after insertion sort in python

Tags: python

```
def binary(arr,key):

  low = 0

  high = len(arr)-1

  found = False

  while low<=high and not found:

    mid = (low+high)//2

    if arr[mid] == key:

      found = True

      index = mid

    elif key<arr[mid]:

      high = mid-1

    else:
      low = mid+1

  if found == True:

    print("key found index: ",index)

  else:

    print("not found")
```

This list ask user how many values u want to add

```
value = int(input("how many number u want to add"))

arr = [0] * value

for n in range(value):

    arr[n] = input("Enter value")

print("unsorted array: ")

for n in arr:

    print(n, end="  ")

for n in range(1, len(arr)):

    temp = arr[n]

    j = n - 1

    while temp < arr[j] and (j >= 0):

        arr[j + 1] = arr[j]

        j = j - 1

    arr[j + 1] = temp
```

it show error  if value < alist[midpoint]:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
in line 10

Comment: key = int(input("Enter key "))
binary(arr, key) these are last 2 line of code

Comment: You might want to get rid of all the extra vertical lines... it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: `arr` is of type `List[str]`, but `key` is of type `int`. Your types don't match.

Comment: `arr[n] = int(input("Enter value"))`.

Comment: how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the type error is that `arr` is a `List[str]`. You can fix this by changing it to type `List[int]`:

```
for n in range(value):
    arr[n] = int(input("Enter value"))
```